# How to log every login (SSH) on FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, logging, freebsd, login

I want to log every SSH login attempts, both successful and not, to my FreeBSD server to a file, and daily mail this log to root.

I could accomplish something like this by parsing `/var/log/auth.log`, but a) this contains more than login attempts, and b) it could be turned over since yesterday's run. Is there a more direct way of doing this; for instance a hook in SSHd or login configuration to log each login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default is to log to the `AUTH` facility. You can change the `facility` that sshd logs to with the `SyslogFacility` configuration option.

```
SyslogFacility LOCAL7
```

Then configure your syslogd to write local7.* to it's own file by adding

```
local7.*     /var/log/local7.log
```

to the syslogd configuration file. Tell syslogd to reread it's config file by sending it a `HUP` signal do the same for sshd and you should have sshd messages being sent to it's own file.

Comment: Thank you! :-) This is one possible solution. I also found another; PAM scripting -- see my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon **[this blog-post](http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html)** that describes multiple solutions to my question. Among other things it mentions log-parsing and, interestingly, **PAM scripting** through `pam_exec`. This enables me to run my own script on every login.

I think this is the most flexible solution to my problem, although `Iain`'s previous answer probably is less invasive and also solves my problem.